# How to parse MTOM soap response in c#

Tags: c#, soap, .net-core, mtom

I want to parse the web service response which is in soap MTOM format.
It is the response

```
--MIMEBoundary_437235bf25f089af96e3a1387b60bdfbd52e58e56b20f9b0
Content - Type: application / xop + xml; charset = utf - 8; type = "text/xml"
Content - Transfer - Encoding: binary
Content - ID: < 0.737235bf25f089af96e3a1387b60bdfbd52e58e56b20f9b0 @apache.org >

    <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
    < soapenv : Envelope xmlns: soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
    < soapenv:Body >
    < sendDataResponse xmlns: a = "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns = "http://org/emedny/fts/" >
    < output >< fileName > ABC.x12 </ fileName ></ output >
    </ sendDataResponse >
    </ soapenv:Body >
    </ soapenv:Envelope >

    --MIMEBoundary_437235bf25f089af96e3a1387b60bdfbd52e58e56b20f9b0--
```

i have tried using XmlDictionaryReader but it is giving error 
"The Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) message encoding is not supported on this platform."

```
string MTOM = response;

MemoryStream ms;
ItemOperations obj;
DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ItemOperations));

string fixedMtom = MTOM.Replace(
    "Multipart/Related;boundary=437235bf25f089af96e3a1387b60bdfbd52e58e56b20f9b0;",
    "Multipart/Related;boundary=\"437235bf25f089af96e3a1387b60bdfbd52e58e56b20f9b0?MTOM\";");
ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fixedMtom));
XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateMtomReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
```

I want to extract the file name from soap element.How can i get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse/deserialize MTOM/XOP Data .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531128/parse-deserialize-mtom-xop-data-net)

Comment: My response does not contains <xop: Include href > tag. It has only mime boundary. I want to to extract only xml part from this.so that it can load xml document to get the file name

Comment: You tagged .net-core, be explicit about that. Maybe MTOM is not supported (yet) on Core.

Comment: Please [edit] and re-post that xml. Copy paste the text and use `[{}]`to format as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work using Regex.  Lost of issues with space in the xml :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication117
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            string pattern = @"(?'xml'\<\?.*)--MIMEBoundary";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input,pattern,RegexOptions.Singleline);
            string xml = match.Groups["xml"].Value.Trim();

            string pattern1 = @"\<[?/]?((\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+)|(\s*\w+))";
            xml = Regex.Replace(xml, pattern1, ReplaceSpaces);
            string pattern2 = @"\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*=";
            xml = Regex.Replace(xml, pattern2, ReplaceSpaces); //remove spaces in namespaces

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            string filename = (string)doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "fileName").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        static string ReplaceSpaces(Match match)
        {
            string input = match.Value;
            string pattern = @"\s*(?'name1'\w+)\s*(?'colon':)*\s*(?'name2'\w*)";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "${name1}${colon}${name2}");
            return output;
        }
    }
    public class Player
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I want to extract only file name node. So removing mime part from outside the xml document and after that read the particular node text will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

parse xml structure using VS (Edit/Paste as json or xml) or [enter link description here](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

```
     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "output", Namespace = "http://org/emedny/fts/")]
        public class Output
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "fileName", Namespace = "http://org/emedny/fts/")]
            public string FileName { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "sendDataResponse", Namespace = "http://org/emedny/fts/")]
        public class SendDataResponse
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "output", Namespace = "http://org/emedny/fts/")]
            public Output Output { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "a", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
            public string A { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
            public string Xmlns { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public class Body
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "sendDataResponse", Namespace = "http://org/emedny/fts/")]
            public SendDataResponse SendDataResponse { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public class Envelope
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
            public Body Body { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
            public string Soapenv { get; set; }
        }


.....


using (var st = File.OpenRead(@"i_saved_your_request_here.xml"))
{
    var data = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope)).Deserialize(st) as Envelope;
    var output = data.Body.SendDataResponse.Output.FileName;
}
```